# I want to create a small square colour filled box in HTML & CSS. And most important - I want to write one line after the box

Tags: html, css

i have created colored squre box using code

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='box red'></div>= Super Fast Trains<br>
<div class='box green'></div>= Mail/Express Trains<br>
<div class='box blue'></div>= Local/ Passenger Trains
```

But I want the text beside the boxes which is not showing in this current code.I also tried 'float:left' attribute but that making the second & third lines not showing in same margin. 
See the code at https://jsfiddle.net/14to4gej/

So please help me with correct modification in my code to get text after boxes an in same margin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: look for "clear float" or "float clearfix", `clear` is a CSS property to force floating items to "go to a new line" sort of. Here is an example with a (maybe outdated style) clearfix: https://jsfiddle.net/14to4gej/8/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try next:

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div><div class='box red'></div>= Super Fast Trains</div>
<br>
<div><div class='box green'></div>= Mail/Express Trains</div>
<br>
<div><div class='box blue'></div>= Local/ Passenger Trains</div>
```

Comment: No need for a live link. Make a snippet in your answer (I did it for you)

Comment: thnx max its easy , i have to change a little in my code to archive my goal

Answer (score 27):

How about using the square html entity?

```
<div style="color:blue">&#9632;</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the `before` pesudo selector and create a box before your content/text.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.box:before{
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  content: "";
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.box.red:before{
  background-color:red;
}
.box.green:before{
  background-color:green;
}
.box.blue:before{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='box red'>= Super Fast Trains</div>
<div class='box green'>= Mail/Express Trains</div>
<div class='box blue'>= Local/ Passenger Trains</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/14to4gej/21/

Comment: ok thanks works,,, little bit hard than other's solution but it may be better as i have not used the :before earlier,,, so i dont know its usages. thanks again

Answer (score 5):

As usual, what is a pain to achieve with classic CSS (float, clearfix, inline-block, etc.) is a breeze with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :

```css
.row {
    display : flex;
    align-items : center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right : 5px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class='box red'></div>
  <span>= Super Fast Trains</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class='box green'></div>
  <span>= Mail/Express Trains</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class='box blue'></div>
  <span>= Local/ Passenger Trains</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just wrap your box and text into div with margin and add vertical-align. https://jsfiddle.net/14to4gej/24/

```
div:not(.box) {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box {
    ...
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first i'll suggest to choose to use the `:before` tag as @Keja advise or you can actually wrap the two elements inside an html tag like `div` or `p` for example and then style them in Css:

```
 <div class="option-one">
      <span class="box red"></span>
      <p>= Super Fast Trains</p>
 </div>
 <div class="option-two">
      <span class="box green"></span>
      <p>= Mail/Express Trains</p>
 </div>
 <div class="option-three">
      <span class="box blue"></span>
      <p>= Local/ Passenger Trains</p>
 </div>
```

Second don't use `br` because is not semantic. If you want two items in different visual blocks, you probably want them in different logical blocks.

In most cases this means just using different elements, for example `<p>Text</p><p>Other text</p>`, and then using CSS to space the blocks out properly.

There are cases where `<br>` is semantically valid, i.e. cases where the line break is part of the data you're sending. This is really only limited to 2 use cases - poetry and mailing addresses.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanx your advice about <br> will help me in next projects

Answer (score -2):

Put the text inside a header or `<p>` inside the `<div></div>` Then it will be inside the box. To move it to the left, just add padding on the left.

Comment: Instead of telling OP what to do, demonstrate your point with some working code.